# How to set permissions for an uploaded file when using store() or putFile()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

From Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads

I can upload a file from the request using either:

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

or

```
$path = Storage::putFile('avatars', $request->file('avatar'));
```

The docs also mention how to set permissions for files: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-visibility

Which is to set the permissions for `public` or `private` in the config, then use `put()` method. But when I get files from the request I need to use `putFile()` or `store()`, not `put()`, so how can I set permission in this case?

Comment: what permissions do you need?

Comment: ``Storage::putFile('avatars', $request->file('avatar'), 'public')`` ?

Comment: or use ``$request->file('avatar')->storePublicly('avatars');`` for public visibility.

Comment: @lagbox the permissions I set in the filesystem (0777 for example): https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#local-files-and-visibility

OMi Shah, I don't want publicly, it's private user uploads. so if I use `store()` it means "privately"?

Comment: @B.DLiroy, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use public storage if you don't want the file to be public.

I don't know if it's the best way to check permission on a file, but this is what I do when I need to give access on a file to specific users:

```
use Storage;

class AdmissionFileController extends Controller
{
    public function show(AdmissionFile $admissionFile)
    {
        $this->authorize('view', $admissionFile);

        $mimetype = Storage::mimeType($admissionFile->path);
        return response(Storage::disk('local')->get($admissionFile->path))->header('Content-Type', $mimetype);
    }
}
```

In this example, the path of the file is stored in DB on AdmissionFile. I use Policies to check the permission to view the file:

```
class AdmissionFilePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user, AdmissionFile $admissionFile)
    {
        return $user->id === $admissionFile->user_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not what he meant by permission. He's talking about file visibility: public and private.

Comment: My bad sorry, should I delete the answer?